# How can I replace the result of startsWith() function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, replace, ecmascript-6

Here is my code?

```
var cookies = document.cookie.split(';').filter( (c) => c.startsWith('name'));
//=> [name_twitter=true, name_instagram=true]
```

While this is the expected result: `[twitter, instagram]`. So I need to chain `.replace()` function at the end of `.startsWith()` function. Like this:

```
var cookies = document.cookie.split(';').filter( (c) => c.startsWith('name').replace(/.*_(.*)=true/, "$1"));
```

But it throws:

> Uncaught TypeError: c.startsWith(...).replace is not a function

How can I fix it?

Comment: `startsWith` performs a check and returns a boolean value.

Comment: `var cookies = document.cookie.split(';').filter( (c) => c.startsWith('name')).map(c => c.replace(/.*_(.*)=true/, "$1"));`

Answer (score 0):

Your problem here is that `startsWith` returns a boolean (`true` or `false`). And replace operates on a `String` so you need to check with something like:

```
var cookies = document.cookie.split(';')
  .filter( (c) => c.startsWith('name') )
  .map( (c) => c.replace(/.*_(.*)=true/, "$1") );
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do a filter and then a map:

```
var cookies = document.cookie.split(';').filter(c => c.startsWith('name')).map(c => c.replace(/.*_(.*)=true/, "$1"));
```